# Android http connection CAN'T connect to localhost CAN connect to external website

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have got this code on my application, that I copied and pasted from stackoverflow. All it does is do a http request to a website, and return its content (and it works perfect).

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        responseString = out.toString();
                        out.close();
                    } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ShowMsg(thisone,result);
}
}
```

When I use it to get the content of a website, like this way:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

It was perfectly well. It shows the entire code of the website, and everything nice. But when I try to get the content of a website I have running on my apache server, it shows nothing:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://127.0.0.1");
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Localhost from android is .... the android phone. You need to put in the name or ip of your apache server.

So if you are running a local emulator, you should put in the IP of your machine.

Comment: LOL!! Of course... its a virtual machine, what was I thinking off. So the answer is 192.168.1.11 for me. Thanks a lot!